# When closing form and returning to previous, it keeps opening instances of the form

Tags: c#

```
Reports_FormClosing(Object Sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Dashboard dash = new Dashboard();
    dash.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

[image: This is the form that just keeps going until it times out]

Is there something I need to do with the ResumeLayout event?

Comment: The code shown explicitly opens an instance of a form.  Are you saying that it suddenly happens many times when you close the form which hosts this code, or that it opens a single instance of `Dashboard` each time you close the form which hosts this code (and the screen shot is the result of closing the form many times)?

Comment: I had Reports open, when closing the Reports form (with the default control buttons), it closes the Reports form and just keeps opening up many Dashboard forms faster than a human can click out of them. So I guess it's opening up more than 1 instance but very fast.

Comment: It's been ages since I've used WinForms, but perhaps one doesn't need to (and/or shouldn't) call `this.Close()` in the `FormClosing` event?  Since the form is already closing, explicitly closing it again really shouldn't be necessary I would think.  If it's just re-invoking the `FormClosing` event then what you'd have is an infinite loop.  What happens if you remove that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is responding to the `FormClosing` event:

```
Reports_FormClosing(Object Sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
```

And one of the things this code does is close the form:

```
this.Close();
```

Which triggers the `FormClosing` event, which closes the form, which triggers the `FormClosing` event, and so on, and so on.

The form is already closing, you don't need to tell it to close.  Just remove that line.